# como hacer que SQL Server me cambie el status de un registro de forma automatica cuando llegue cierta hora?

Tags: sql-server

estoy haciendo un sistema de colas y necesito qque despues de 30 minutos que el usuario ingreso a la cola, el sistema cambie su estatus de true a false pero sin ninguna peticion al servidor, que lo haga directamente en la base de datos, se puede?

Comment: Con qué versión de SQL Server estás trabajando?

Answer (score 0):

Lo más sencillo, a mi entender, armar un JOB que se ejecute cada 30 minutos, el cual verificaría un "Fecha de ingreso a la cola" si superó los 30 minutos con relación al `GETDATE()`, realice el UPDATE que mencionas.